# Apex Trigger failing with 101 SOQL error

Tags: apex, trigger

**Apex Trigger:**

```
trigger Duplicate_email on Lead (before insert, before update) {

  map<string, Lead> leadMap = new map<string, Lead>();

  for(Lead lead : system.trigger.new){

    if((lead.Email != null) && (system.Trigger.isInsert || (lead.Email == system.trigger.oldMap.get(lead.id).Email))){

      if(leadmap.ContainsKey(lead.Email)){
        lead.Email.addError('Another new lead has the' + ' same email address');
      }else{
        leadMap.put(lead.Email, Lead);
      }
    }
  }

  for(Lead lead : [SELECT Email FROM Lead WHERE Email IN : leadMap.keySet()]){
    Lead newLead = leadmap.get(lead.Email);
    if(!leadmap.get(lead.Email)){
      newLead.Email.addError('A lead with this email address'+' already exist');
    }
  } 
}
```

I'm trying to prevent the duplicate lead creation based on  Email. But throwing a SOQL limit error when inserting a large sets of lead records.

**Error:**

System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries 101.

Comment: Can you please share some details? What are your actions before this error? Are you sure that problem is in this trigger? It can be used in other logic etc.

Comment: If you are searching for duplicate Lead with the email address, then better to use Aggregate function with GROUP BY and HAVING clause

Comment: even better is to use SFDC Duplicate Management (except for intraTransaction Leads where trigger code is still required)

Comment: problem is not with this code, however I want to point out that
'for(Lead lead : [SELECT Email FROM Lead WHERE Email IN : leadMap.keySet()])'

this line is incorrect, you are trying to find EMAILS in IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ray indicated, this trigger is bulkified, however you might want to review the other triggers on the object, this help document has good references
[Salesforce Knowledge Article: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181404&language=en_US)

Now to prevent duplicate emails on leads, you don't need code.
Just do the following:
Create a new email  field called Unique_Email, make it unique
create a Workflow rule that fires with the following criteria:

```
IsNew() || ISChanged(Email) && NOT(ISBLANK(EMAIL)
```

The in that WFR, create a field update that sets the value of the field UniqueEmail__c as the value of the standard field Email, so the formula would simply be:

```
Email
```

That way, whenever somebody changes the email address of a lead or creates a new lead, the email will be set in unique_email__c field, if it's not a unique value the out of the box error will be display(it's a really nice error too that gives a link to the other record with the same value)

Comment: Is this something I can make this for a specific record type on lead?

Comment: Yes, you can control it from the Workflow rule, by NOT running the WFR except on certain recordtypes, say you have a record type named "New Lead" an you don't want it to run on records with this RT then the formula of the WFR would be:
`IsNew() || ISChanged(Email) && NOT(ISBLANK(EMAIL) && RecordType.Name != 'New Lead'`

you can also run it only on certain record types by remove the !

Comment: if my answer solved your problem please mark it so.

Answer (score 3):

This code is correctly bulkified, and as such will only ever issue one SOQL query, no matter the number of records input.  The issue is not with this trigger on Lead, but perhaps some other code that is executing.